# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm aware about similar kind of issues posted on Stackoverflow and happened to try them out, however they havnt worked out for me.Can anyone please help me with this error???Below is the event I'm triggering to get the popup:

`'click(li.ui-element')   : 'modifyUser'` on click of this `li` event, a popup is be generated.

```
modifyUser: function(event) {
var popUp, template,user;
popUp = $('#confirmation-popup').empty();
template = $.mustache(_this.templates['groupPopup'], user);
return popUp.html(template);
WPM.ui.dialog(popUp, {width: 400, 
buttons: {
   Save: function() {user = popUp.data('user');
         user.save()
   });

   if (user.save()) {
     return $(this).dialog("close");
   }
 },

Cancel: function() {
  $(this).dialog("close");
},
});
```

Also are there any other ways to display pop-ups beside the UI-Dialog??

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return popUp.html(template);` in your code before the dialog is initialized. That won't get run. Move the return statement to after you initialize the dialog.